# Round based on number of decimal places of scientific notation float

Tags: python

I would like to return the rounded values of `num`, where the number of decimal places passed to `round()` are the number of decimal places of the `floats` in `[scis]`.

```
scis = [5e-05, 5e-06, 5e-07, 5e-08]
num = 0.0123456789

returns:
0.01235
0.012346
0.0123457
0.01234568
```

In order for something like this to work, I need to derive the number of decimal places from each item in `sci` to pass to `round`.

I wasn't able to come up with an answer reviewing  [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) or [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary), and for reasons described in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), using a method like this produces too many decimal places:

```
import decimal

scis = [5e-05, 5e-06, 5e-07, 5e-08]

for sci in scis:
    d = decimal.Decimal(sci)
    dp = abs(d.as_tuple().exponent)
    print(dp)

67
70
73
74
```

Am I relegated to having to parse the string definition of scientific notation in order to derive the number of decimal places, or is there a less naive way to approach this?

```
scis = [5e-05, 5e-06, 5e-07, 5e-08]
num = 0.0123456789

for sci in scis:
    place = int(str(sci).split('-')[-1:][-1])
    print(round(num, places))

0.01235
0.012346
0.0123457
0.01234568
```

Comment: What's the reason for the necessity of basing the rounding off of the scis array? Are these numbers fixed (such as 5e-7), or just examples and could be anything, like 1.23e-6?

Comment: They are examples and could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some math transformations on the numbers using `log10`

```
from math import log10, ceil

for sci in scis:
    z = round(num, int(ceil(abs(log10(sci)))))
    print(z)
0.01235
0.012346
0.0123457
0.01234568
```

Comment: This worked well.  Thanks for the tip.